# Passing variables between forms Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, variables

I'm quite a noob when it comes to classes, subs and that kind of stuff. I'm making a program in VB 2012 that will create a portable version of Minecraft on your USB key.

Here's some code ("port_cr"):

```
    'Get %appdata%
    Dim appdata As String = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\AppData\roaming\.minecraft"
    'Get the path
    port_mc_getPath.ShowDialog()
    Dim save_mc As String = port_mc_getPath.SelectedPath
    'Copy everything
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(save_mc & "\Data")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(save_mc & "\Bin")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(save_mc & "\Data\.minecraft")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(appdata, save_mc & "\Data\.minecraft", True)
    'OPEN ANOTHER FORM TO CHOOSE THE LAUNCHER YOU WANT TO DOWNLOAD
    chooseLauncher.Show()
```

"chooseLauncher" is a form with some buttons that download the appopriate files to the path specified in the "port_cr" form, which is what I can't figure out how to do. If someone could tell me how to do this simply I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create public properties on the `chooseLauncher` form and set them to the values before you show the form.  For instance, if the `chooseLauncher` form had a public string property called `SaveMc`, you could do this:

```
chooseLauncher.SaveMc = save_mc
chooseLauncher.Show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms are just fancy types of classes that have some visual behavior / rendering associated with them.  In OOP, you can  treat them the same way you would treat any class, either custom or native.

Let's take a simple native class in the .NET framework and abstract out from there.
How do you pass data to the class DataTable?

```vb
'create a new instance of that class
Dim dt as New DataTable
'pass in the name of the table
dt.Name = "AnyName"
```

I can pass that information to the datatable class because it already has a property that can store the Name info.

Now think about this when you create your own classes.  Let's say you have a form which is called ChooseLauncher.  Let's give it some properties that it can use internally and be added externally.  Perhaps a property called FilePath

```vb
Class ChooseLauncher : Inherits Form

    Public FilePath As String

End Class
```

Now when you create the ChooseLauncher class.  All you have to do is set the publicly available properties from wherever you created it.

```vb
Dim myForm As New ChooseLauncher
myForm.FilePath = "NewValue"
myForm.Show()
```